# Regex ['!@#$%*\]\[()-=_+{}:\";?,.\/A-Za-z0-9\s] is allowing < character

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, regex-group

I am using https://regex101.com/ to test my below regular expression but this expression is allowing < character which is not mentioned in the expression.

```
['!@#$%*\]\[()-=_+{}:\";?,.\/A-Za-z0-9\s]
```

Comment: `-` creates a range, escape it.

Comment: can you please explain..

Comment: You either need to put `-` at the start or end of the set or escape it with ``\`` such that you end up with `['!@#$%*\]\[()\-=_+{}:\";?,.\/A-Za-z0-9\s]`

Comment: @ctwheels : Thanks you..

Comment: You can also use `[!-%'-\/:;=?@[\]{}\w\s]` which is shorthand for everything you wrote (but uses ranges to cover characters instead of explicitly writing them all). If you don't want to you use that you can use a slightly shorter version `['!@#$%*\]\[()=+{}:\";?,.\/\w\s-]` that replaces `A-Za-z0-9_` with `\w`

Comment: This expression is working fine and not allowing < > & returning false for the same but if I am using these special character within a complete string like below code I am getting a true response any idea.?
functionA = function () { var value = "sdfhf$#%##<>" ; var val = new RegEx("['!@#$%*][()=_+{}:\";?,.\/A-Za-z0-9\s-]"); return val.test(value); }

Answer (score 8):

`-` denotes a range inside a character class.

The range you're matching in your regex is all the characters that appear between ")" and "=", because:

```
['!@#$%*\]\[()-=_+{}:\";?,.\/A-Za-z0-9\s]
             ↑ ↑
```

And the "<" sign appears between them (see [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)):

[image]

You need to:

- escape it, or
- move it to the end (or beginning) of the class

Change to:

```
['!@#$%*\]\[()=_+{}:\";?,.\/A-Za-z0-9\s-]
```

---

Simpler example:

```
[1-9]
```

matches digits from "1" to "9", while:

```
[19-]
```

and

```
[1\-9]
```

matches "1", "9" and "-".

Comment: @ctwheels Rejected as no free hand red circles were detected (just kidding, thanks!).

Comment: This expression is working fine and not allowing < > & returning false for the same but if I am using these special character within a complete string like below code I am getting a true response any idea.

Comment: functionA = function () {                                                                                var value = "sdfhf$#%##<>" ;                                                                            var val = new RegEx("['!@#$%*\]\[()=_+{}:\";?,.\/A-Za-z0-9\s-]");                        return val.test(value);                                                                                            }